# Multidimensional array storing/printing issues

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a parser for use at work. Basically I have an excel document full of rows of data that I need to parse through and store into a multidimensional array to work with.

Here is the code I have so far:

```vb
Dim a 
Dim iRows As Long 
Dim i As Integer 
Dim aArray() As Variant 

a = Array(2,3,4,5,6,9,10,14,19,21,23,25,29,38) 
iRows = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
ReDim aArray(iRows, UBound(a))

For i = 2 To iRows + 1 
    For x = 0 To UBound(a) 
        aArray(i - 2, x) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, a(i - 2)).Value 
    Next x 
Next i
```

Keep in mind the offset of `i = 2` and `iRows + 1` is to ignore the header row

The problem is that when I attempt to output it I am finding that all the rows are the same so `aArray(0,1)` and `aArray(1,1)` are the same values which they should be different values from different rows of the excel file.

furthermore there should be 14 columns that I am storing per row but when i try to output any value past location 9 i get an out of range error like so

```vb
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = aArray(10, 0)
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = aArray(11, 0)
```

Based on the small array I am using to specify which values to store in the main array their should be 14 total locations for each sub array contain within aArray.

Any insights?

Keep in mind that this is my first real VBA script so if I am making mistakes please have patients with my I m coming from a JS/PHP background so this is a lot different for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You switched the dimensions in aArray. In the code you redim and fill aArray with (count_of_rows_in_usedRang,count_of_elements_in_a) and I imagine used rang is just 9 lines, so aArray(10, 0) is out of range while aArray(0,10) wouldn't be.

I think there may be a similar problem with the output in the first part of your question. If not: please post, what is in the excel-sheet and what you got as a result.

Comment: ya i ended up having to switch the first two values and the the next occurrence of i - 2 in the output needed to be x like so    aArray(x, i - 2) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, a(x)).Value     works perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to simply read data from a worksheet, ignoring the headings, you're over complicating it. Something like this will work:

```
Const intOffsetRow As Integer = 2

Dim rngUsedRange As Range
Dim varWksArray As Variant

Set rngUsedRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange

With rngUsedRange
    varWksArray = .Range(Cells(intOffsetRow, 1), Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)).Value
End With

Set rngUsedRange = Nothing
```

If you don't mind there being a blank / empty row / dimension in your array, it can be simplified even further:

```
Const intOffsetRow As Integer = 1

Dim rngUsedRange As Range
Dim varWksArray As Variant

Set rngUsedRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange

varWksArray = rngUsedRange.Offset(intOffsetRow, 0).Value

Set rngUsedRange = Nothing
```

Comment: He wants to copy a whole range, rearranging some cells in it. There probably are better methods to do this - I think he did a good job keeping it simple and versatile (just change a() if you need other rows or if you need them in another order).